# TableSorter filter - remove all rows with a given keyword

Tags: tablesorter

I am displaying a table with tablesorter that has column filtering and would like to add a button that would remove all rows in which the word "error" appears in a certain column.  I managed to create a button that would essentially just throw

```
!error
```

to the filter but I would prefer that it leaves the filter field open so that one can still use it and retain the removal of the error rows.

I tried the method from [TableSorter - External Search, Trying to search from button to filter all, not just column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588516/tablesorter-external-search-trying-to-search-from-button-to-filter-all-not-j/28638923?noredirect=1#comment62057006_28638923) but while it can find all the columns with "error", putting "!error" doesn't work since even a row that contains "error" also has columns that don't contain it.  Anyone know of a way to hide those rows while still retaining the filtering ability on the remaining rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not (`!`) query applied to all columns was [previously ignored](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html#limitations); but tablesorter v2.26.2 was just released and it now allows those type of search queries.

Try [this demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) - click on the `!aaron` button to test it.